# encrypting HSQLDB: select CRYPT_KEY not working

Tags: java, encryption, hsqldb

I'm trying to get a AES encryption key generation by a HSQLDB database to work. The documentation of this feature is very basic and the only code listing for this task i found here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/515884/JDBC/databases/Encrypted-database-HSQL

Unfortunately this Code is not working i get a java.sql.SQLException: invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is empty

here is the code from the coderanche post:

```
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:some_db", "SA", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select CRYPT_KEY('AES', null) from some_table");
    rs.next();
    String key = rs.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to get a key:

```
CALL CRYPT_KEY('AES', null);
```

Comment: thx for your answer, its working now. I also got another working solution in the HSQLDB Support Forum:
SELECT
CRYPT_KEY('AES', NULL) FROM (VALUES(0)) is working as well

Comment: I am not understanding it. What i assume is that we are creating database and then we are creating table in it and after that we apply crypt_key() function on that table, and what we get is a key (if 3 records then 3 keys) which we go back and apply to already created DB in hsql? is that so? If not, please help me in complete sample code

Comment: First you get a key using any other database, then you create the new database using that key.